# Getting SVN to work in Xcode 4

Tags: svn, xcode4

I have a Subversion 1.7.1 repository hosted on our Unix server, I can do anything I want from Windows 7 + Eclipse, but on a mac with os x 10.7
I get the following error:

```
Authentication realm: <svn://193.27.72.xx:3690> c7701390-2c01-11e1-a266-3bca917d80ec
Password for 'svnuser': 
Authentication realm: <svn://193.27.72.xx:3690> c7701390-2c01-11e1-a266-3bca917d80ec
Username: svn: Can't read stdin: End of file found
```

Username and password are correct, I added 193.xx.xx.xx Subversion to hosts file, and even added access in keychain. I can list the repositories from command line and it doesn't prompt me for a password there.

What else can be done to make Subversion working from xcode?

Answer (score 0):

XCode does not work with Subversion 1.7 yet. You have to downgrade your SVN version in order for it to work nicely with XCode.